# How to convert culture specific double using TypeConverter?

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

I have a problem with the `TypeConverter` class. It works fine with `CultureInvariant` values but cannot convert specific cultures like English thousands separators. Below is a small test program that I cannot get to work.

Here's the problem :) - `ConvertFromString` throws an exception with the following message *"2,999.95 is not a valid value for Double."* and with the inner exception *"Input string was not in a correct format."*.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.ComponentModel;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            var culture = new CultureInfo("en");
            var typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(double));
            double value = (double)typeConverter.ConvertFromString(
                null, 
                culture, 
                "2,999.95");

            Console.WriteLine("Value: " + value);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
Link to the bug report on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/553254/cannot-parse-thousands-separators-using-typeconverter-convertfromstring#details)

Comment: What is not working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: ConvertFromString is throwing an exception: "2,999.95 is not a valid value for Double."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `DoubleConverter` that is obtained from `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(double))` end ups calling `Double.Parse` with the following arguments:

```
Double.Parse(
    "2,999.95", 
    NumberStyles.Float, 
    (IFormatProvider)culture.GetFormat(typeof(NumberFormatInfo)));
```

The problem is that `NumberStyles.Float` does not allows thousands separators and that's why you are getting the problem. You can submit this on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/) or see if anybody else had the same problem.

If `Double.Parse` is called also with `NumberStyles.AllowThousands` the problem would not occur.

```
Double.Parse(
    "2,999.95", 
    NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, 
    (IFormatProvider)culture.GetFormat(typeof(NumberFormatInfo)));
```

Comment: But the example is more closely related to using Double.Parse without any NumberStyles, in which case Double.Parse will work.

Have just comitted it as a bug on Connect. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @Christian, if you don't mind could you update your question and add the link to the Connect issue?