# 1.000.000 is not a valid value for Double c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, globalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert culture specific double using TypeConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688949/how-to-convert-culture-specific-double-using-typeconverter)

I am getting an exception while trying to parse an "1.000.000" string to `Double` by using `TypeConverter`.
I looked at the `System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo` at the moment of exception and it looks like this:

```
{System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo}
    CurrencyDecimalDigits: 2
    CurrencyDecimalSeparator: ","
    CurrencyGroupSeparator: "."
    CurrencyGroupSizes: {int[1]}
    CurrencyNegativePattern: 8
    CurrencyPositivePattern: 3
    CurrencySymbol: "TL"
    DigitSubstitution: None
    IsReadOnly: false
    NaNSymbol: "NaN"
    NativeDigits: {string[10]}
    NegativeInfinitySymbol: "-Infinity"
    NegativeSign: "-"
    NumberDecimalDigits: 2
    NumberDecimalSeparator: ","
    NumberGroupSeparator: "."
    NumberGroupSizes: {int[1]}
    NumberNegativePattern: 1
    PercentDecimalDigits: 2
    PercentDecimalSeparator: ","
    PercentGroupSeparator: "."
    PercentGroupSizes: {int[1]}
    PercentNegativePattern: 2
    PercentPositivePattern: 2
    PercentSymbol: "%"
    PerMilleSymbol: "‰"
    PositiveInfinitySymbol: "Infinity"
    PositiveSign: "+"
```

Everyting seems fine to parse "1.000.000" but it says "1.000.000" is not a valid value for `Double`. What is the problem?
I tried to override `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` but it did not work either.

EDITED :::::::::

This seems to solve my problem as well. TypeConverter actually works without ThousandSeperator. I added one and it started to work.

possible duplicate of How to convert culture specific double using TypeConverter? – Rasmus Faber
[How to convert culture specific double using TypeConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688949/how-to-convert-culture-specific-double-using-typeconverter)

Comment: One or two words to your current culture, the desired culture, the code you use to parse the string and how you looked at the NumberFormatInfo?

Comment: Post it as a small but complete piece of code.

Comment: Actually I  make it a small console application on LINQPAD4, it did work. But it doesnt seems to work on the large application itself. Is there anything else to looked at

Answer (score 2):

Try this `NumberFormatInfo`:

```
var s = "1.000.000";
var info = new NumberFormatInfo
{
    NumberDecimalSeparator = ",", 
    NumberGroupSeparator = "."
};
var d = Convert.ToDouble(s, info);
```

You can change `NumberDecimalSeparator` to something else, as long as it's different from `NumberGroupSeparator`.

EDIT: the `NumberFormatInfo` that you've specified should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

`Most normal numerical types have parse methods. Use TryParse if you're unsure if it's valid (Trying to parse "xyz" as a number will throw an exception)`

`For custom parsing you can define a NumberFormatInfo like this:`

```
var strInput = "1.000.000";
var numberFormatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo
{
    NumberDecimalSeparator = ",",
    NumberGroupSeparator = "."
};
double dbl = Double.Parse(strInput, numberFormatInfo);
```

this solution will work also

```
var format = new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo();
format.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
format.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
double dbl2 = Double.Parse("1.000.000", format);
```